# How to create a column whose background stretches to the far left of the screen, but not the content?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how I can create a layout similar [to this](http://choiseul.info/), where the pages content is constrained by the container element's width, but the column on the left has a background that stretches to the far left of the user's screen (the yellow one in the example).

I'm trying to do this with Bootstrap, but it seems impossible as the container element contains the content of the page and also it's background.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8093/) for what I have so far.

Some sample code of the structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-6 left-one">
            This one's background needs to stretch to the far left, on large screens.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 right-one">
            This one's background can be that of the body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="some-content">
    <div class="container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos minima laudantium, id a, porro aliquid expedita. Iste beatae provident architecto dolorum aspernatur maiores, ratione deserunt nesciunt magni unde repudiandae eaque.
    </div>
</div>
```

Would really appreciate if someone can solve this mystery for me.

Here's the full code:

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

body{
    background: #eee;
}

.left-one{
    background: yellow;
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.right-one{
    background: #eee;
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.some-content{
    background: lightslategray;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-6 left-one">
            This one's background needs to stretch to the far left, on large screens.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 right-one">
            This one's background can be that of the body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="some-content">
    <div class="container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos minima laudantium, id a, porro aliquid expedita. Iste beatae provident architecto dolorum aspernatur maiores, ratione deserunt nesciunt magni unde repudiandae eaque.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That site uses Inuit CSS, so just use Inuit and their markup as starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do what the guy have done in example & use the before element.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8095/)**

**CSS:**

```
.left-one:before{
    background: yellow;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 9999px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Forgot how powerful pseudo elements can be and overlooked the before element while inspecting the site.